# Reference for Dimensional Regularization

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I am studying a bit of theoretical physics (QFT and string theory), and I obviously stumbled upon [dimensional regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization). I have been told that this technique has in fact a solid mathematical theory behind. I'd like to learn more on this, and I was wondering if anyone got some nice reference on the subject (books or papers are well accepted).

Thanks in advance.

---

I have found [this script](http://www.phys.vt.edu/~ersharpe/6455/janhand1.pdf) of prof. Eric Sharpe. It is a good explanation of the "how to", but it still doesn't explain when it's possible/sensible to apply dimensional regularization, nor why/when does it work (mathematically speaking).

I am also trying to read a paper a professor of mathematical physics gave me on the subject. If/when I'll understand it I will edit this post once again, or write an answer myself (if meanwhile nobody else does).

Comment: Cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138005/dimensional-regularization-in-odd-dimensions perhaps?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thanks for the reference. I tried to take a look at the paper cited in the answer to that question, but it's too deep in QFT for me to understand with my very limited knowledge of the subject.

Comment: If this is still of interest, take a look at [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92411/what-exactly-is-regularization-in-qft) on Physics.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks. :)